# using Laravel lists function to retrieve a huge number of items

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, where-in

I have a `Group` model that ***belongsToMany*** `Contacts`, and `Contact` ***belongsToMany*** `Groups`,  usually a group could contain about 300,000 contact, and a contact could belong to 2 or 3 groups, and I want a function that retrieves all "unique" contacts in a number of given groups, so I tried

```
$contacts = Contact::With(array('groups'=>function($query) use ($groups)
{
    $query->whereIn('groups.id' , $groups);
}
))->get();
```

It worked but the problem is that I discovered the sql generated uses where `contact_id IN ( ALL CONTACTS' IDs)`. So, if I'm retrieving 100,000 contacts it will have 100,000 of contact ids in the where in clause.

Then I ended up using this

```
foreach($groups as $group)
{
   $contacts = array_unique(array_merge($contacts , $group->contacts()->lists('email'))) ;
}
```

But I'm still concerned about performance. I don't know how lists works and if it is a good idea to `array_unique` and `array_merge` on arrays containing hundreds of thousands of email strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> usually a group could contain about 300,000 contact, and a contact
>   could belong to 2 or 3 groups

According to this your relationship should be [many-to-many](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many) and both `Group` and `Contact` should use `belongsToMany` to make relationship between them using a pivot table `contact_group`:

```
// Group model
public function contacts()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Contact');
}

// Contact model
public function groups()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Group');
}
```

The `contact_group` pivot table could be like this:

```
id | group_id | contact_id
```

If you have a setup like this then you'll be able to do this:

```
$groups = Group::has('contacts')
               ->with('contacts')
               ->whereIn('id', [1,2,3]) // group ids, could be any field
               ->get();

$uniqueContacts = $groups->map(function($group) {
    return $group->contacts->lists('email');
})->flatten()->toBase()->unique();

// You got all unique contacts in $uniqueContacts
dd($uniqueContacts); // all unique contacts
```

Don't know how fast it'll work on `100,000` contacts but should work better.

**Update:** Could be other (maybe better) ways by joining `DB` tables and querying from `DB` scope.